# Probability function for group service time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need help with the following problem: A batch of n items arrives at a service station where all items are being serviced simultaneously in parallel. The service time for each item is a stochastic variable and the time (t) to service each item has the same probability function:

```
                        P1 = f(t), where t is time;
```

The n items will be completed at different times but The batch will not be released until the last item has completed service. I am looking for the probability density function for the time until release of the batch as a function of n and t:

```
                        Pn = F( n, f(t) )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
Let $M:=\max\{T_1,\ldots,T_n\}$ where $T_i$ denotes the service time of item $i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. You need to calculate $F_M(t)=P(M\le t)$ for $t>0$.

---

To check: $$F_M(t)=P(M \le t)=P(T\le t)^n=F_T(t)^n$$ so $$f_M(t)=nF_T(t)^{n-1}f_T(t)$$